# Proof for sum of vertex polygons in polyhedra

Tags: angle, polyhedra

What's the rigirous proof for the statement:

When the internal angles meeting at a vertex are added, if the sum $<360$ then it's the polyhedra is convex, if the sum $= 360$ it's flat and $>360$ is concave.

Answer (score 0):

The statement you gave, being out of context, clearly is wrong.

Even when considering the additional restriction to uniform polyhedra only, then there still exist counterexamples for your proposition: e.g. the [small stellated dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_stellated_dodecahedron) (one of the Kepler-Poinsot solids) has 5 regular pentagrams per vertex, i.e. it has a local sum of $\,5\cdot 36°=180°<360°$, but because of using pentagrams it clearly is a (globally) non-convex (aka concave) polyhedron.

Btw., would you think that this magic would occur only because of the starry facial pentagrams? Well then consider a usual regular [icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedron) with the top-most pentagonal pyramidal cap dimpled inwards instead. Then the such deformed polyhedron obviously becomes concave, while the local vertex sum still remains $\,5\cdot 60°=300°<360°\,$ all over on any of its vertices!

--- rk

Comment: What about the case for sum $= 360$?

Comment: build a larger cube from 8 smaller ones in a $2\times 2\times 2$ configuration. Now withdraw a single smaller cube. The remainder obviously is concave. But still there are 3 remaining vertices at the face centers of the larger cube, which have $4\cdot 90°=360°$ for the according vertex sum.